# c# DataGridView, always only getting the first cell value

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a button click that is supposed to grab the value of the selected cell.  However, it only gets the first cell in the datagrid view.  I'm not sure if this is a property I need to change or what.

The form is loaded from another form upon a button click.  Here is the SQL table being loaded into the DataGridView:

```
enter code herepublic void progressView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        getSQLJobStatus();
    }

    public void getSQLJobStatus()
    {

        string connectionString = @"Data Source=FCMONITOR\AVIDAUTO;Initial Catalog=InterplayWatchFolder;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter aFiller = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [JOB_ID], [WORKFLOW_NAME], [JOB_NAME], [TRANSCODE_TRANSFER_STATUS], [DATE] FROM AVID_WATCH_JOBSTATUS", connection))
            {
                DataTable jobStatusDT = new DataTable();
                aFiller.Fill(jobStatusDT);

                progressView.DataSource = jobStatusDT;
                connection.Close();
            }
```

There is a button labelled "Cancel" on the same form as the datagridview.  I am trying to get the JOB_ID value from the selected row.  I've tried with CurrentCell and SelectedRows but still only get the first cell's value.

Here's what I have as the current code of the button click:

```
 string getJobID = progressView.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: are you using MVVM or code-behind? and is it a windows store app?

Comment: It's a console app using Win 7 forms.  And forgive my ignorance since I'm new to this, I'm not sure what you are asking with MVVM and code-behind.

Comment: _a console app using Win 7 forms._ Um, now what, Console or Winforms?? Console apps don't have buttons and can't show a DGV. Are you really sure you __have__ selected another cell?? Did it turn blue?

Comment: MVVM is a architectural pattern used when developing apps like Windows store app. You probably mean windows forms application right?

Comment: It's a console application that had windows forms added to it.

Comment: CurrentCell should reffer to a focused cell. How do you select the cell?

Comment: Selected by user in datagridview.  It then shows as the highlighted cell to the user.

Comment: If all you are doing is **1.** Clicking a cell; then **2)** Clicking the button and you're always getting the same value, then we need to see more code on your setup - because that alone is not enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: I added how the datagridview is loaded from the SQL db to the original question.  Hopefully that's what you need.  Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: The exception you get when accessing the SelectedCells collection indicate that in fact no cells are selected. Not sure how that can be, but the console+form setup may be getting in the way. You can try to code the mouseclicked or cellclicked events to keep track of the clicked cell.. Of course you should NOT use the cellCONTENTclicked event!!

Comment: I think I finally found what was up.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
progressView.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString()
```

Comment: It throws this exception: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: setting selection mode might help:  `progressView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.CellSelect;`

Comment: Still only grabs that first cell value.

Comment: use CellClick event, then you can get the clicked cells value  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are only ever getting the first cell's value because that's frequently the `CurrentCell` from user mouse interaction.

Logic flow:

1. User clicks a cell's content.
2. `CellContentClick` triggers `getSQLJobStatus`

   - This updates the grid's `DataSource`
   - Which in turn resets the `CurrentCell` to cell `[0,0]`

You can verify this by clicking a different cell's content - on mouse down the clicked cell highlights, on mouse up the first cell is now highlighted.

The user can still focus any other cell by clicking the cell outside of the content or navigating there via Tab, Enter, and arrow keys. But as long as you update the source whenever they click in a cell's content, you will see this behavior. I recommend updating the `progressView.DataSource` somewhere else independent of the sourced `DataGridView`and its event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a solution.  I changed SelectionMode to FullRowSelect.  For some reason it was automatically set to ColumnHeaderSelect.

The cold also looks like this now:

```
string getJobID = progressView.SelectedRows[0].Cells["JOB_ID"].Value.ToString();
```